# Many-to-many to DTOs using Automapper

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, automapper, dto

If I have a many-to-many relationship defined in EF:

```
public class StudentImage 
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentImage> Images { get; set; }
}


public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentImage> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And the DTO's:

```
 public class ImageDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentIDO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ImageDTO> Images { get; set; }
    }
```

How could I map from Student to StudentDTO and from Image to ImageDTO using Automapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mappings

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Student, StudentIDO>();

Mapper.CreateMap<StudentImage, ImageDTO>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ImageId))
        .ForMember(d => d.Filename, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Image.Filename));

Mapper.CreateMap<StudentIDO, Student>()
      .AfterMap((s, d) =>
      {
          foreach (var studentImage in d.Images)
              studentImage.StudentId = s.Id;
      });

Mapper.CreateMap<ImageDTO, StudentImage>()
      .ForMember(d => d.ImageId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id));
```

Usage

```
var studentDTO = Mapper.Map<StudentIDO>(student);
var student = Mapper.Map<Student>(studentDTO);
```

Comment: I changed the key types from int to Guid and now I'm getting an Automapper exception:  Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping Guid -> Int32, System.Guid -> System.Int32. Destination path:
StudentIDO.Id.Id. The only int field I have is the Order.

Comment: @EduardoBrites that's because Guid cannot be mapped to int. What integer value are you expecting for `458D34DC-5524-47F8-8507-F5AB9234063B`? Change your DTOs ids types to Guid

Comment: The first mapping (from Student to StudentDTO) it's OK, but in the opposite mapping (from StudentDTO to Student), the Image and the Student fields of the StudentImage entity are null.

Comment: @EduardoBrites you have ids of image and student - that should be enough. Otherwise there would be circular dependency problem - student has image which has students, which has images etc

Answer (score 0):

So Image and ImageDTO is relationship 1:1.That's easy mapping by AutoMappper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageDTO>();
```

Mapper.CreateMap();
The last Student and StudentDTO, they have include list.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Student,StudentDTO>
.ForMember(s => s.Images, opt=>opt.MapFrom(p=>p.Images));
```

Sometime if you try that it not good for performance.
Thanks