# Automapper having trouble with foreign key to the same table

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, automapper

I am having some automapper issues.

After adding `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` to my code I get the following error:

```
The following property on CollectiveDistributedPolling.AnswerDto cannot be mapped: 
    Answer
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type CollectiveDistributedPolling.AnswerDto.
Context:
    Mapping to property Answer from System.Int32 to CollectiveDistributedPolling.AnswerDto
    Mapping to property QuestionAnswer from CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionAnswer to CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionAnswerDto
    Mapping to property QuestionAnswer from System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionAnswer, CollectiveDistributedPolling, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionAnswerDto, CollectiveDistributedPolling, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
    Mapping from type CollectiveDistributedPolling.Question to CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionDto
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.
```

So there is an error mapping Answer to AnswerDto, but the mapping should be straight forward (see below)

```
[DataContract]
    public class AnswerDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string answer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<QuestionAnswerDto> QuestionAnswer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<UserAnswerDto> UserAnswer { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Answer
    {
        public Answer()
        {
            this.QuestionAnswer = new HashSet<QuestionAnswer>();
            this.UserAnswer = new HashSet<UserAnswer>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string answer { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserAnswer> UserAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

**Mappings**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<QuestionDto, Question>();

private Question MapToQuestion(QuestionDto q)
{
     return Mapper.Map<QuestionDto, Question>(q);
}
private QuestionDto MapToQuestionDto(Question q)
{
     return Mapper.Map<Question, QuestionDto>(q); <<<< ERROR HERE
}
```

Here is the *SQL table of Question*. As you can see there is a foreign key constraint from Question(next) to Question(ID).

[image: SQL table of Question]

This is a part of my *Model.edmx*

[image: Model.edmx]

If you have any more questions please ask.

Comment: Is `Next` also a `QuestionDto` object? Also, what are the datatypes of your objects? There certainly could be an issue with `Next`, but the error implies that AutoMapper is trying to map an `int` to a `QuestionDto`. Just glancing at the diagrams, it's not entirely obvious as to why, though.

Comment: Next is a `Question` object. Ill post more info about the object.

Comment: Also, I have no idea why it is trying to map `int` to `QuestionDto`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the way EF works with DTOs could be throwing AutoMapper of tack. Remember that with AutoMapper, you can specify exactly what to do on a property-by-property basis.

Going off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441321/many-to-many-to-dtos-using-automapper), for example, you could try something like this:

```
// target = QuestionDto, source = Question
Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionDto>()
      .ForMember(target => target.ID, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.ID));
```

You can also tell AutoMapper to ignore `Next` and handle it directly after the mapping:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionDto>()
       .ForMember(target => target.Next, options => options.Ignore())
       .AfterMap(source, target => {
           // do some magic here
           // source = Question, target = QuestionDto
       });
```

Or, you can switch gears completely and try following [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145062/using-automapper-to-unflatten-a-dto), which suggests using [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to flatten/unflatten DTOs instead of Automapper:

> *use http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/, it does flattening and unflattening, and anything else you need, there is an asp.net mvc sample application in the download where all the features are demonstrated (also unit tests)*

Comment: Thank you!

I have tried your first method but I get weird errors

`Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionDto>()
.ForMember(dto => dto.QuestionAnswer, opt => opt.MapFrom(q => Mapper.Map<QuestionAnswer, QuestionAnswerDto>(q.QuestionAnswer)))`

Do you have an idea what is wrong with this line of code? Id so I owe you big time!

Comment: As long as you have `Mapper.CreateMap<QuestionAnswer, QuestionAnswerDto>()` defined, you shouldn't have to specify a `MapFrom` there. AutoMapper should just kind of do it.